# wx/app.h: no souch file or directory with cygwin64

Tags: c++, makefile, cygwin, wxwidgets

Its nearly impossible to find a compiled version of Meteorite. And when you find one, it doesn't work.

Trying to compile meteorite myself from this github fork: https://github.com/cbielow/meteorite I am met with the following error message when I try to execute the "make" command in Cygwin64:

```
In file included from src/MeteoriteApp.cpp:18:0:
src/MeteoriteApp.h:13:20: fatal error : wx/app.h: no souch file or directory with cygwin64
```

One of the prerequisites are wxWidgets that I have installed with the windows installer from there: https://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/

I am extremely new to c++ everything related to it. What can I be doing wrong? Is there an include in the source from Meteorite that I should change?

wxWidgets installed under `C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0` and here (`C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\include\wx`) I found a `wx` folder with the `app.h` file that the compiler is telling me about. I tried copying this wx folder to different places around the source, and in the  source I tried changing the include from  to <../wx/app.h>. But none of this helped.

Is there anything other than the references given I can provide here to help you guys help me?

Comment: No sure, you probably need to add as dependency the path C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\ where your header are located. Regards

Comment: @Squazz, also, did you just installed wxWidgets or you also compiled the library? You should compile the library prior to using it.

Comment: @Igor I installed it with the windows installer from the wxwidgets website. If I should do anything else, I don't know how to :)

Comment: You probably just need to change (or add to) the include paths you pass to the compiler so that it knows where to find the required header.

Comment: @JesperJuhl that actually did change something. Changing wx/app.h to C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\include\wx/app.h gave me a new error, and now I start seeing the rabbithole... app.h includes "wx/event.h" which is now the next file the compiler cannot find. I don't intend to change all paths in all of the files in wxWidgets, I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: @Squazz I did *not* mean "change the include directive in the source file". I meant "pass an extra include path (`-I` for gcc) to the compiler so it searches that directory as well" - that way it will also find all the *other* includes.. Edit the *build files*, *not* the *source files*.

Answer (score 0):

You must include/edit path of the wxWidgets header files in your project. Try this:
Go to your Enviroment Variables by Click on the This pc -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Enviroment Variables. In the System variables click New and Set the Variable name as: **WXCONFIG** that uses in the makefile. Set the **variable value** as your wxWidgets folder path.

Answer (score 0):

to search file on cygwin packages you can use
https://cygwin.com/packages/

looking for `wx/app.h`

https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Flibwx_baseu3.0-devel%2Flibwx_baseu3.0-devel-3.0.3-1&grep=wx%2Fapp.h

will show you that it is included in the package `libwx_baseu3.0-devel`  the `wxWidgets C++ application framework`

Comment: I didn't understand anything of this. I may be too new with the to understand your answer, but, how do I use this information to solve the problem at hand? :)

Comment: Install `libwx_baseu3.0-devel` package. Add `/usr/include/wx-3.0` to your include search path

Answer (score 0):

If you look inside wxWidgets samples you will find projects set to include wxWidgets correctly. The thing that matters sometimes is to create a new project in a custiom location so you must set the include and library directories correctly.

This is an example of wxWidgets:

```
// additional include directories
.\..\..\lib\vc_lib\mswud
.\..\..\include
.
.\..\..\samples
```

To set a project on the desktop for example:

```
D:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\lib\vc_lib\mswud
D:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\include
D:\wxWidgets-3.1.0
D:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\samples
```

Above as you can see my wxWidgets is installed on drive D so if I want to use it in my projects I set the directories as above.

- Also do the same thing with additional libraries:

  ```
  D:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\lib\vc_lib
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin is (supposed to be like) Unix, so you should follow Unix instructions for building wxWidgets itself and applications using it, see, for example, `docs/gtk/install.txt` in the distribution.

Notice that you will need to build wxWidgets itself first and then build the application using `wx-config --cxxflags` as explained in the file above.

Also notice that you've probably chosen the *least* simple way to build the application by using Cygwin as your platform. Using MinGW+MSys would be simpler.